# Identify five basil-like herbs

Tags: identification, herbs, basil

Are these basils? If so, what kinds? (When there is more than one kind of plant in a picture, I'm asking about the one in the center.)

Thank you.

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]

Comment: @Droseracapensis Yes, I can and did smell them. In fact, I've been eating them, and still I can't tell. So great is my ignorance. 3 and 5 smell like basil to me. 4 smells like lemongrass. 2 smells like mint and 1 like some kind of medicine.

Comment: We have this “one plant per identification question” rule, please see [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info). You are welcome to post multiple questions and can even cross-link them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what they look like to me:

1. Holy basil or mint
2. Mint
3. Mint
4. I want to say mint, but it looks a bit different. Not sure.
5. Marjoram, or possibly oregano; if it is a basil, then probably Spicy Globe Bush

Some mint-like plants may be other things, such as pennyroyal or horse mint.